# How to stream video on demand?

Tags: javascript, java, angular, angularjs

I want to able to play video on demand. I have Spring Boot Java app as a server and Angular/JavaScript app as a client. What I want to accomplish is that whenever a user want to play video on a browser, sends Rest API request to server side. The server side sends chunks as byte array. Then the client side converts that byte array and starts playing the video using HTML5 `<video>` tag.

The issue: I have the server side sending the video file as chunks of byte array, reading it from FileInputStream

```
public byte[] streamMovie(String filepath) throws IOException {
    int SIZE = 1024 * 1024;
    File file = new File(filepath);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filepath);
    byte[] v = IOUtils.readBytesAndClose(fis, SIZE);
    return v;
}
```

But on the client side, I can't find any solution that can convert this byte array in to suitable format, that I can use to create a blob in JavaScript;

On Client side

```
const player = document.getElementById("video-player");

// response is the response came from the server side i.e. byte array
const uint8array = toUint8Array(response.data);

const blob = new Blob(uint8array, { type: 'video/mp4' });
player.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
player.play();

function toUint8Array(data) {
    let byteNumbers = new Array(data.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        byteNumbers[i] = data.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF;
    }
    const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
    return byteArray;
}
```

Then I keep getting:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.
```